# Zip end of central directory signature not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubyzip

I'm trying to allow for a user to upload a zipped folder containing xsl stylesheets.
I then want to unzip the folder and save the folder in `Rails.root/public/xsl/folderName`

Here's what I'm trying in my action:

```
require 'zip'

Zip::File.open(params[:stylesheet].tempfile) do |zipFile|
  zipFile.each do |file|
    path = File.join(Rails.root.join('public','xsl'),file.name)
    File.open(path, 'wb') do |f|
      f.write(file)
    end
  end
end
```

I'm getting `` Zip::Error: Zip end of central directory signature not found from /GEMS/gems/rubyzip-1.3.0/lib/central_directory.rb:143:in `get_e_o_c_d` ``

This error is happening on the first line of the code. I've tried zipping the folder through 7Zip and sending the folder to Window's "Compressed (zipped) folder".

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`Zip::Error: Zip end of central directory signature not found from /GEMS/gems/rubyzip-1.3.0/lib/central_directory.rb:143:in get_e_o_c_d`

- Error indicates: Perhaps, the .xlsx file was corrupted also You can discover that the zip is corrupted or not by trying to unzip it from your code.
- In solutiions: The content by forced it to encode as utf-8, and handle the buffer file after the upload also extract its data after it. I suggest to use the code of
  roo-xls gem, and it's handle both .csv/.xlsx files very easy way.